# How Do I Specify View List in Joomla Controller?

Tags: php, list, view, joomla, components

I am building a joomla 2.5 component, but I am having some issues with the pluralization of the `$view_list` value in the component's view file.  Can you please show me a code example of how I can go about specifying a unique value for `$view_list` and thus over ride the automatic value that is loaded through the plural english form?

Here is a link to a similar discussion: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=642&t=668428

Essentially I need to be able to "specify the correct name of the list view in your controller" as mentioned by radiant_tech.  How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In the "singular" controller file (like car.php) create the following constructor:

```
public function __construct($config = array())
{
    $this->view_list = 'carz'; 
    parent::__construct($config); 
}
```

The controller should redirect now to "carz" and no longer to "cars".

Let me know how it turns out for you.